# Silent (no user interaction) utility to clear cached credentials on Windows

Tags: authentication, windows, privacy, logging

Is there any way to clear cached credentials on Windows, that doesn't require:

- user interaction (e.g. a confirmation window);
- administrator access; or
- making a persistent change to the configuration, such as tampering with the registry?

A function implemented in a DLL is fine, I can write a small utility around it.

Who wins there — accountability or privacy?

Comment: No.  The type of action you are seeking to do requires a user profile with administrator priviliages.

Comment: @Ramhound A DLL can be a system level driver. If it were previously loaded, this is not entirely outside the realm of possible.

Comment: @JeffFerland The DLL could bypass items #1 and #2 I suppose, but we're still stuck with item #3 regardless.

Comment: @Iszi Perhaps the asker means without user interaction to the registry. Since cached credential keys are stored in the registry, it must be modified. To the asker: is the goal to make a single library call without the programming needing to acquire specialized permissions under the idea the library would already have privileged rights?

Comment: Question is too vague. The requested action requires some combination of the 3 requirements. The OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @JeffFerland - A system level driver would require administrator to install which means it would fail #2 and my statement is still true.

Comment: @Ramhound And this is just another reason the question is too vague.  The limitation of not having Administrator access is not well-defined.  Could the method require one-time Admin access for initial setup, while not requiring Admin access for normal operation, or is Admin access just entirely out of the question?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no".

---

Cached credentials are maintained in special Registry keys.  These keys are only accessible by the SYSTEM account.  In order to impersonate the SYSTEM account, you must have Administrator access to the system.

You *might* be able to write a script or something that can bypass #1.  However, in the absence of any flaw in the OS (which cannot be reliably presumed, since it would likely be patched at some point), you cannot likely avoid #2.  And, since the cached credentials *are* stored in the Registry, #3 is non-optional no matter how you want to do it.

I believe you can get away without using the SYSTEM account, by modifying the configuration options that define how the system handles cached credentials instead of messing with the cache itself.  However, this will still violate your #2 & #3 requirements because the options are stored in the Registry and do require Administrator permissions to modify.  Additionally, it may require one or two re-logins or reboots to be effective.

---

***Sidenote***:  This question, as currently written, is perhaps more appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).  Nevertheless, the answer remains the same.

---

**EDIT**:  For more information about where the cached credentials are stored and how to modify settings which affect them, you may want to check out my [related question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/375036/54923).